# Custom post order returning posts from other categories

Tags: posts, loop, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to order each post in a category by custom field (using Advanced Custom Fields Plugin)

```
 $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'meta_key'   => 'adult_price',
   'orderby'=> 'meta_value_num',
   'order'  => 'ASC'
 ));
 if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
     get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
   endwhile;
 endif;
```

The problem is that it's somehow returning posts from **ALL** other categories.

Comment: On which page is this. If it is category.php or taxonomy.php, remove your custom query, and use `pre_get_posts` to do your custom ordering

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In WP_Query(), there is no category reference passed so this is the point which returns all category post.

Please try with passing category ID here:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
   'cat'=4, //Your category ID
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'meta_key'   => 'adult_price',
   'orderby'=> 'meta_value_num',
   'order'  => 'ASC'
 ));
```

OR

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
   'category_name'=staff,   //Your category name...
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'meta_key'   => 'adult_price',
   'orderby'=> 'meta_value_num',
   'order'  => 'ASC'
 ));
```

Hope this would help you better.

Thanks!

Comment: `category_name` use the category **slug**, not the name. The naming convention is stupid and misleading :-)

Comment: First answer works when using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829632/get-current-category-id-of-the-active-page to get current id